# how to see ListBox like DataGridView ? (connect ListBox to DataBase)

Tags: c#, asp.net

how i can see ListBox like DataGridView ?

i want to connect ListBox to any DataBase and see it like DataGridView.

thank's in advance

Comment: Hi, could you provide more information? What do you mean with "like datagridview"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `ListView` instead of a `ListBox`.  To make a `ListView` look like a `DataGridView`, you need to set its `View` property to `Details`, its `HeaderStyle` to `Clickable` or `Nonclickable`, and then add one or more `ColumnHeaders` to its `Columns` collection (you can do this easily from the properties windows, or add them in code).  You would generally add one column header for each field of data from the database table you wish to display.

Assuming that you have a `DataTable` named `dt` filled with the data you wish to display, you would add it to a `ListView` named `listView1` with code somewhat like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(
        new string[] {
            row["FirstName"].ToString(),
            row["LastName"].ToString(),
            row["Age"].ToString()});
    lv.Items.Add(item);
}
```

For this example code to work correctly, you would add three `ColumnHeaders` to the `Columns` collection ("First Name", "Last Name" and "Age" - note that the text of the column headers does not have to exactly match the field names in the `DataTable`).

However, you might have an easier time just using a `DataGridView` for this, since it can be quickly and simply bound to a `DataTable` without any code like this.